# Java2D Unstable Delta Time

Tags: java, 2d

So I want to run my new game using delta time, but the problem is that the delta is too unstable. Meaning that it usually puts out between 8 and 11 witch is good, but sometimes spits numbers like -4000 and over 5000. But the screen is updating every 10ms... I dont see how it happens.

```
setEndTime((int) System.nanoTime() / 1000000);
            setDelta(getEndTime() - getStartTime());
setStartTime(getEndTime());
```

Is it just the fact that javas Timer class is inacurate?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a simple example? Have you tried watching your memory consumption to see if GC is running whenever the time spikes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.nanoTime() returns a long, but you are casting to an int, this may be the cause,
try using longs to keep track of time and see if that helps.